# Safe way to get origin

Tags: javascript

I am maintaining an application in which I access the origin via `window.origin` in order to build some URLs.

It works... but I had a security alert because it seems that this variable can be written. For example, go on Google and try that in the dev tools :

```
> window.origin
<   'https://www.google.com'
> window.origin='yolo'
<   'yolo'
> window.origin
<   'yolo'
```

This is indeed a security issue as my URLs are built like this : `window.origin + "/path/to/other/app"`
If an attacker could find a way to execute this script `window.origin = 'evil.com'`, customers would be redirected to an unexpected URL.

I found that I could call `location.origin` instead, which seems safer :

```
> location.origin
<   'https://www.google.com'
> location.origin='yolo'
<   'yolo'
> location.origin
<   'https://www.google.com'
```

But does it work on every browser ? Is there a recommended way of getting the origin ?

Comment: `But does it work on every browser?` Is that your question? Why shouldn't it work? [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin) is fine.

Comment: why is `window.origin='yolo'` a security issue? your users will always be able to modify the URL (and get error 404)

Comment: @RicardoAranguren suppose you go on paypal and I find a way to make you execute `window.origin="evilpaypal.com"` that I supposedly own. The next time you click on a button that uses this variable, you would be unknowingly redireced to my website. I would make it a copy cat of the original paypal site and you would enter login/password.

Comment: `The next time you click on a button that uses this variable`, since the DOM is client sided available, you can **always** alter the target of a button/

Comment: @0stone0 `window.origin` looks like it works on every browser, but then I discover the security issue. `location.origin` looks like it works on every browser but I don't know if it is actually `readonly` on every browser. The questions are 1) is `location.origin` safe on every popular browser ? 2) Is it the recommended way of doing it or is there a better solution ?